# How does reddit update it's favicon on the fly without running into caching problems?

Tags: favicon

Whenever I change a favicon on a site I work on, it can take hours/days for the browser to re-request the new resource.

But when I go to reddit, if I have a message I get a notification in the favicon, without a page load as well, I think?

Is this as simple as supplying a new favicon with a different filename?  How do you get the browser to load that without doing a page load?